# AMPscript syntax to resolve an anchor tag to the end of a Personalization String

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for the correct syntax to resolve an anchor tag to the end of a Personalization String.

The current personalization string is:
href="%%microsite_base_url[default]1825398[/default]%%"

I would like to add #tab02 to the end of the string.

The end result would preform the same way as the following: (with the benefit of passing a personalization string)
href="http://pages.aulrs.oneamericaemailservices.com/page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea2f0281e5b868f3b9f85ca63acb216c77a0112230fad6d40a#tab02"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add more detail? This question is very broad

Comment: Hey Stephen - this is definitely not e2.0 account? Is that returning anything?  Not sure what I'm trying to reproduce in my account exactly.  Just need some more detail.

Comment: I'm looking for the correct syntax  to resolve and anchor tag to the end of a Personalization String. -- I've got a page id of 1825398 and I would like to link to a a specific anchor tag withing the page. The unique id in the page in this example is #tab02. The standard Personalization String for a landing page is: href="%%microsite_base_url[default]1825398[/default]%%"

Comment: Edit your question with that bit of clairty, and I'll have @metadaddy open this back up, as I think the solution should be straight forward. Is the goo.gl as an example of what you are trying to get to?

Comment: Yes the Goo.gl is a landing page inside ET.

Comment: Reopened!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Super simple to do.

Create a variable (`@url`) and set to `%%microsite_base_url[default]1825398[/default]%%`

Create a variable (`@variable`), and set the variable to `concat(@url,"#tab2")`

Then in href: `%%=v(@variable)=%%`

Should set it.

Comment: This is the same answer i would have posted. Should just need to concat the data together.